# python Tkinter: scrollbar is not adding to the textarea

Tags: python, tkinter

the follwing code in a serparate file is working fine. It is creating a text area and adding a scrollbar to it.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
text=Text(root,height=10,width=50,background='pink')
scroll=Scrollbar(root)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
```

But exactly same code is not woking when it was merged with other code (**main.py**)

```
//================ other code
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+100+0") # width, height, x ,y
button_1 =  Button(root,text="iphone file")
button_1.pack()
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_1.configure(command=openFile)

//------------------ following is the same code
text=Text(root,height=10,width=50,background='pink')
scroll=Scrollbar(root)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.config(command=text.yview)
text.pack(side=LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
```

and when i running main.py file from cmd prompt, it just hanging. what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use both `grid` and `pack` for the same containing widget. You cannot do that. You either need to use `grid` for the text and scrollbars or use `pack` for the buttons.